# Proof of the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem:** Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,\,b]$ and assume $f(a)<f(b)$. Then for every $k$ such that $f(a)<k<f(b)$, there exists a $c\in[a,\,b]$ such that $f(c)=k$.

---

*proof:* $f$ continuous at $a\implies$ for $\varepsilon=k-f(a)>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $$|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon=k-f(a)\quad\forall x\colon |x-a|<\delta.$$ Consider the set $H=\{x\in[a,\,b]\colon f(x)<k\}\not=\emptyset \implies c=\sup{(H)}$. Show $f(c)=k$, suppose $f(c)<k\iff k-f(c)>0$. We know $f$ is continuous at $c$ so $\forall\varepsilon>k-f(c)>0$ $\exists\delta>0:|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon=k-f(c)$ when $|x-c|<\delta$. $\implies f(x)-f(c)<k-f(c)$. Say $x=c+\delta/2\implies f(x)<k\implies c+\delta/2\in H$ which contradicts the fact $c=\sup{(H)}$, since $\delta>0$. Same proof works if $f(c)>k$, thus $f(c)=k$.

---

This is a proof for the intermediate value theorem given by my lecturer, I was wondering if someone could explain a few things:

- What is the set $H$, what does it define?
- Why does contradicting the fact that $c=\sup{(H)}$ prove that $f(c)\not<k$?
- How would I continue to actually finish this proof, ie. show $f(c)\not>k$?

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: the first line of th proof has no sense... i.e $\forall \varepsilon=k-f(a)>0$...

Comment: @user2850514 But if the $\;\epsilon\;$ is "specific" then that quantifier there makes no sense at all. Even worse, it confuses.

Comment: The "Therefore $\;f\;$ is continuous (where? at **all** $\;x\in [a,b]\;$?) iff (??) $\;f(x)<k\;$" is very strange, and if true then you've proved the IVT isn't true as $\;f(x)\neq k\;\;\forall\,x\in [a,b]\;$ ...! Unless, of course, you meant something else. There are other incorrect, or at least messy, things: $\;f\;$ is understood to be continuous at $\;a\;$ *only from the right*, and thus a neighborhood $\;|x-a|<\delta\;$ doesn't make much sense, etc.

Comment: @user2850514:  I'm sad to read your last comment ! :'( I downvoted because all what you said is totally unclear !

Comment: So what could I do to make this proof correct then? This is what my lecturer has provided.

Comment: @user2850514 Your lecturer gave you the "proof" you wrote in your question?

Comment: It's worth noting that the Intermediate Value Theorem is false in Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis (SIA). Straying into 'SIA territory' won't help prove it.

Comment: You should tell us what part of the proof you are not sure about!

Comment: @user2850514 Please do delete that new question you posted! It is very bad seen to post new questions every time we want to edit our question: do it on this very question! Besides this, you once again wrote that incorrect and confusing quantifier!

Comment: I deleted that question. I have changed the quantifier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The set $H$ is the set of elements $x\in [a,b]$ for which $f(x)<k$.

Since this set is bounded, it has a supremum $c\in[a,b]$. There are three cases:

1. $f(c)=k$
2. $f(c)<k$
3. $f(c)>k$

In the first case, you're done.

Suppose $f(c)<k$. In particular $c\in H$ and, moreover $a<c<b$, because by assumption, $f(a)<k$ and $f(b)>k$. By continuity of $f$ at $c$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $a<c-\delta<c+\delta<b$ and
$$
|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)<k
$$
(by considering the continuous function $k-f(x)$ which is positive at $c$). But then $c+\delta/2\in H$, because $f(c+\delta/2)<k$. A contradiction to the fact that $c=\sup H$.

Suppose $f(c)>k$. By the same argument as before, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $a<c-\delta<c+\delta<b$ and
$$
|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)>k
$$
But, by definition of supremum, there is $x\in H$ such that $c-x<\delta$; for this $x$ we have both $f(x)<k$ and $f(x)>k$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I have a few questions here: Why does $f(a)<k<f(b)\implies a<c<b$? Secondly, did you derive $|x-c|<\delta\implies f(x)<k$ the same way my lecturer did? (ie. same was as in the above post)

Comment: @user2850514 In the case $f(c)<k$ it's clear that $c<b$. It's also $c>a$ or $H=\{a\}$ (then argue why this can't happen). If $f(c)>k$, then $c>a$; if $c=b$, then $H=[a,b)$ (argue why this can't happen). Yes, I did the same as your lecturer: just consider $k-f(x)>0$.

Comment: @egreg One question. For the case that f(x) < k, would be correct to say, instead of your argument, that in that case, delta + c would be the supremum, and as "If a set has a supremum, then it has only one supremum" then there are two supremums, a contradiction.

Comment: @Beginner Why should $\delta+c$ be a supremum?

Comment: @ because the absolute value of x-c is less than delta because f is continuous, right?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your fast answer. However, I want to know why I cannot use just that c plus delta, or maybe c plus delta max will be a new supremum, a contradiction because we will have two supremums c and c plus delta max.

Comment: @Beginner Well, $c=\sup H$ by definition, so certainly $c+\delta$ cannot be the supremum of $H$.

Comment: @egreg My point is that would be the contradiction because if the absolute value of x-c is less than delta, c+delta would be another supremum. Is that reasoning incorrect?

Comment: @Beginner Yes. It is incorrect.

Comment: @egreg What if we say that x is an element of the interval (c-delta, c+delta). However, if that is true, c would not be the supremum, a contradiction.

Comment: @Beginner What's $x$? Please, I already told you a few times you're wrong.

Comment: @egreg Please accept my apologies.

Comment: Can the set H be defined to be values where $f(x)\leq k$? It seems weird that $c$ would be s.t. $f(c)=k$ if $c$ is in H.

Comment: @Minecraftdirtblock If $c\in H$, then $f(c)<k$, by definition, and we'd be in case 2. Note that $c=\sup H$ need not belong to $H$.

Answer (score 6):

Ideas for a possibly clearer, easier proof:

1) Prove that if $\;f\;$ is continuous at $\;[a,b]\;$ and $\;f(a)f(b)<0\;$ then there exists $\;c\in (a,b)\;\;s.t.\;\;f(c)=0\;$

2) prove the complete IVT by choosing $\;g(x):=f(x)-k\;$ and applying (1) to $\;g\;$ .

Highlights of proof of (1) : WLOG assume $\;f(a)<0\;,\;\;f(b)>0\;$ .  Take the point $\;w_1:=\frac{a+b}2\;$ . If $\;f(w_1)=0\;$ we're done, otherwise choose the interval

$$\begin{cases}\left[\,a\,,\,w_1:=\frac{a+b}2\,\right]&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;f(w_1)>0\\{}\\or\\{}\\
\left[\,w_1:=\frac{a+b}2\,,\,b\,\right]&,\;\;\text{if}\;\;f(w_1)<0\end{cases}$$

Take now $\;w_2=\frac{a+w_1}2\;\;or\;\;w_2=\frac{w_1+b}2\;$ , depending on what interval we chose above, resp. If $\;f(w_2)=0\;$ we're done, otherwise do as above.

Continue the process above inductively

Apply now Cantor's Theorem (of embedded closed interval which lengths tend to zero)  to deduce there's one single point $\;c\;$ in the intersection all these interval, use continuity of $\;f\;$ to show that $\;f(\text{left endpoints of intervals})\to f(c)\;$ , and likewise for right end points, and by construction get

$$0\le f(c)\le 0\implies f(c)=0$$

Fill in details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I haven't however met cantor's theorem and am looking for a much more rigorous proof (by the definition of continuity and such) rather than using numerical methods to approximately find the root.

Comment: Cantor's  Theorem is usually used to prove basic theorems, like Bolzano-Weierstrass in sequences. Haven't you messed with this? And please observe that the above proof is all the rigurous you can expect and there is no approximation **at all** of roots (?) or whatever!