# Forgot the name of a common theorem in calculus

Tags: calculus, terminology

Which theorem states that if $f$ is continuous and attains values of $a$ and $b$ at different points, it must attain all values in between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I don't feel this question is on-topic as it's literally just a matter of googling that exact phrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of the Intermediate Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092358/proof-of-the-intermediate-value-theorem)

Answer (score 3):

Intermediate Value Theorem....